# When you get a new competency at work, you have a new responsibility and a new... power?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

> Suppose you work at Acme doing your usual: fooing the bars. Now you are promoted and this means you have a new **competency**: you will be bazing the quxes as well. Therefore you have the new **responsibility** that all quxes are bazed in due time and you are supposed to propose new quxes as well. To make sure you can perform your new duties, you are given **new powers**: you may prioritize the quxes to baz as you see fit, and also you may assign some quxes to your colleagues.

Did I use the the words competency, responsibility and powers correctly?

Comment: Not really a SWR. But, I would suggest *authority* instead of *power*.

Comment: *Competency* is not something that is granted on promotion, but something that was recognized and justified the promotion. A wily manager once told me: *A promotion usually doesn't mean a role change, but a recognition you are already performing that role.*

Comment: What words can I use then? When I give someone a new responsibility and adequate authority to go with it, what is the "whole package" called?

Comment: Depending on the scope, it is a *task*, *role*, or *project*. The promotion should indicate successful fulfillment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Competency** is not really proper here. Instead I would use **duty** (an action or task required by a person's position or occupation; function) or **commission** (a task or matter committed to one's charge; official assignment).

The use of **responsibility** is fine, but I'd recommend following it with **to ensure that** instead of simply **that**.

Instead of new **powers** I would probably use new **capabilities** (the quality of being capable; capacity; ability).

(All definitions taken from dictionary.com)